# Codeigniter: multi checkbox validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a Codeigniter Project. I have 5 checkbox which set field as display:none.
Once click on the check box the input field visible as below image. Once the input field visible and the input field cannot be empty and i set a validation rules in controller as below which works exactly as expected.

It just that i have to write callback validation for each checkbox for this to work. Is that anyway i can accomplish this differently or use one callback validation for all the checkbox?

[image]

My View

```
    <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="col-3">Select Purpose</label>
           <?php     
             $option1[''] = 'Please Select Purpose of Donation';
             $option1['gnrlprps'] = 'General Purpose';
             $option1['spfcprps'] = 'Specific Purpose';
              echo form_dropdown('purpose_select',$option1,set_value('purpose_select'), 'class="col-9 custom-select" id="purpose_select"' , 'required="required"')
;?></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="spcfc_checkboxes[]" id="research_chkbx" value="Research" <?php echo set_checkbox('spcfc_checkboxes', 'Research'); ?>>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="spcfc_checkboxes[]" id="student_scholarship_chkbx" value="Student" <?php echo set_checkbox('spcfc_checkboxes', 'Student'); ?>>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="spcfc_checkboxes[]" id="chair_chkbx" value="Academic" <?php echo set_checkbox('spcfc_checkboxes', 'Academic'); ?>>
    
    
    <div class="col-9 input-group input-group-solid" id="student_scholarship_input" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">MYR</span></div>
    <input class="form-control student_scholarship form-control-solid" type="text" name="student" value="<?php echo set_value('student');?>" placeholder="Enter Amount">
    
    
    
    <div class="col-9 input-group input-group-solid input-group" id="research_input" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">MYR</span></div>
    <input class="form-control research form-control-solid" type="text" name="research" value="<?php echo set_value('research');?>" placeholder="Enter Amount"></div>
    <?php if(form_error('research')) echo '<span class="form-text text-muted has-error">'.form_error('research').'</span>';?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My Controller

```
 Instead of Callback Validate i did this
```

My Controller

`code`

```
$purpose_select = $this->input->post("purpose_select");
$checkbox = $this->input->post("spcfc_checkboxes");

            if($purpose_select === 'spfcprps'){
            
            if(!empty($checkbox)) 
            {

       
            
            foreach($checkbox as $checked);

            if ($checked === 'Student Scholarship'){
            $student_scholar = $this->input->post("student_scholarship_amount");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_scholarship_amount','Student Scholarship Amount','trim|required');
            
            }            

            if ($checked === 'Academic Chair'){
            $academic_scholar = $this->input->post("chair_amount");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('chair_amount','Chair Amount','trim|required');
            
            }
            if ($checked === 'Research'){
            $research_scholar = $this->input->post("research_amount");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('research_amount','Research Amount','trim|required');
            
            }
            if ($checked === 'Infrastructure'){
            $research_scholar = $this->input->post("infrastructure_amount");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('infrastructure_amount','Infrastructure Amount','trim|required');
            
            }
            if ($checked === 'Others'){
            $research_scholar = $this->input->post("others_amount");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('others_amount','Other Amount','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('others_purpose','Donation Purpose','trim|required');
            
            }
           
            
            }

             if (empty($checked)) {
               
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('spcfc_checkboxes', 'Specific Purpose','required',array('required'      => 'Please check at lease one pupose'));           
           
            } 
            }
```

Comment: do you mean to write a callback to check that at least one checkbox is true, if "specific purpose" input was selected? Or do you need a callback for MYR (enter amount)?

Comment: The callback is to check if checkbox if checked and if it checked, the input field cannot be empty.

Comment: Instead callback i edit the controller as above code. Its works fine just that if two or more input field is empty, it only validate only one input field.